# Getting the actual size of map canvas using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, mapcanvas

How to get pixel size of canvas in QGIS?
It is possibly by Python. I mean this red rectangle area in the image.

[image: example]

Comment: what do you mean with dataframe? If you mean a raster-layer than the pixelsize is in the properties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get those values with this code :

```
qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().size()
```

This returns a `QSize` object. You can catch width and height directly with

```
canvasSize = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().size()    
print("Width : " + str(canvasSize.width()) + " / Height : " + str(canvasSize.height()))
```